# Add animation to DIV based on it's data-info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an SVG map with lots of markers, example of a marker below:

```
<circle class="datamaps-bubble" cx="199.67719373932673" cy="271.2977290725644" r="2" data-info="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Goes&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;51.5061463&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;3.877372599999944&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;animate&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;}" style="stroke: rgb(249, 178, 35); stroke-width: 4px; fill-opacity: 0; fill: rgb(156, 156, 156);" data-previousAttributes="{&quot;fill&quot;:&quot;rgb(156, 156, 156)&quot;,&quot;stroke&quot;:&quot;rgb(249, 178, 35)&quot;,&quot;stroke-width&quot;:&quot;4px&quot;,&quot;fill-opacity&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}"></circle>
```

I have added a 'data-info' attribute to the  map markers called "animated", for example "animated" : "yes". For the  elements that have this "animated" : "yes" attribute I'd like to add (or somehow animate) the marker like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/1694/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried. Or if you haven't tried anything yourself, then it is probably not the time to ask here yet.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by data-info called animated?
Shouldn't you try something like data-animated="yes"?

then access it

```
if($("circle").data("animated")=="yes")
    #code
```

Comment: Thanks for the message - so the data-info is formatted like this: data-info=“{“animate”:”yes”}

Comment: just do data-animate="yes" then access it with jquery like this $("#id").data('animate')

Answer (score 0):

With CSS animations, I would go with:

```
circle[data-animated='yes'] {
  //some animations here
}
```

With JS (using jQuery), I would do:

```
$("circle[data-animated='yes']").coolAnimation();
```